# KVO in swift array not work use Observable

Tags: swift

I use Alamofire to request the data from server like code below,and I want to observe the dataSource,I use https://github.com/slazyk/Observable-Swift.
but `self.tableView?.reloadData()` never be called.

ViewModel.swift

```
var dataSource: [WishOrder] = [WishOrder]()
var observableDataSource: Observable<[WishOrder]> = Observable([WishOrder]())
    Alamofire.request(Router.WishOrder(type: self.type, page: 1, pageAmount: self.pageAmount))
        .validate()
        .responseCollection { (response:Response<[WishOrder], NSError>) -> Void in
            let result = response.result
            switch result {
            case .Success(let value):
                self.dataSource = value as [WishOrder]
                self.observableDataSource.value = self.dataSource
            case .Failure(let error):
                SVProgressHUD.showErrorWithStatus(error.localizedDescription)
            }
    }
```

ViewController.swift

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    ...

    self.viewModel.observableDataSource.afterChange.add { (_) -> () in
        print("afterChange")
        self.tableView?.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your setting your `self.dataSource` up to to be observed after the value has already changed. Try switching lines 9 and 10 up.

Comment: Just from quickly looking at Observable Swift. `.afterChange` method will only be called if a var it is observing changes. Thats why you need to set up the observation before changing the value. Just some fyi.